# My USB media keys don't register

Tags: usb, keyboard, i3-wm, media-buttons

I've recently switched to a new USB keyboard, which has media keys  my system refuses to discover. I've tried using `dmesg` and `xev`, both of which don't output anything on an attempt to use the keys. When I used `evtest`, I found that the media keys have specified event codes on both my 5th and 6th event in /dev/input, but would not return anything on either input.

My systems looks like this:

OS: Ubuntu 17.04

WM: i3-gaps version 4.41

Kernel: Linux version Q550LF 1.0

Keyboard: [Adesso SlimTouch 120](http://www.adesso.com/products/product-detail-229.html)

Any help you could give would be really nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you:

```
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu
```

A review of the Adesso EasyTouch 135 model said "Not Linux friendly. Windows driver to turn lights on and off" so you might contact Adesso.